# css обрезка картинок

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

нужно обрезать и вставить обычную, горизонтальную и вертикальную картинки в div так, что бы они полностью заполняли собой div не искажаясь (масштабировать по меньшей стороне, а лишнее обрезать)

у меня всё работает, кроме обработки квадратной картинки, она должна показыватья почти вся, а видна только ее половина

```css
.img_wrap {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*line-height: 200px;*/
  /*text-align: center;*/
  border-style: solid;
}

.img_wrap img {
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 300px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="img_wrap">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/kgdbvb/v.jpg" alt="vertical" />
  </div>

  <div class="img_wrap">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/gft9Fb/h.jpg" alt="horizontal" />
  </div>

  <div class="img_wrap">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hUgwvb/n.jpg" alt="normal" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 7):

```css
.img_wrap {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.img_wrap img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="img_wrap">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/kgdbvb/v.jpg" alt="vertical" />
  </div>

  <div class="img_wrap">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/gft9Fb/h.jpg" alt="horizontal" />
  </div>

  <div class="img_wrap">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hUgwvb/n.jpg" alt="normal" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.
Сразу вопрос: обязательна ли вставка именно img в тело div-а?
Я бы сделал через background:

```css
.img_wrap {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-style: solid;
}

.bg {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.vert {
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/kgdbvb/v.jpg);
}

.hor {
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/gft9Fb/h.jpg);
}

.square {
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/hUgwvb/n.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="img_wrap bg vert"></div>
<div class="img_wrap bg hor"></div>
<div class="img_wrap bg square"></div>
```

Либо (в случае вставки имено изображения в див) добавить чуточку js - для определения ориентации вставляемого изображения.

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll(".img-frame>img");

function defineOrientation(currentImage) {
  var imageWidth = getComputedStyle(currentImage).getPropertyValue('width');
  var imageHeight = getComputedStyle(currentImage).getPropertyValue('height');
  imageWidth = 1 * (imageWidth.slice(0, imageWidth.length - 2));
  imageHeight = 1 * (imageHeight.slice(0, imageHeight.length - 2));
  if (imageWidth > imageHeight) {
    currentImage.classList.add("hor");
  } else {
    currentImage.classList.add("vert");
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  defineOrientation(images[i]);
}
```

```css
.img-frame {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-frame img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.vert {
  width: 100%;
}

.hor {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-frame">
  <img src="//placehold.it/400x300" alt="horizontal img" />
</div>

<div class="img-frame">
  <img src="//placehold.it/300x400" alt="vertical img" />
</div>
```

Comment: Если картинка содержательно-смысловая - то обязательно