# Изображение на весь блок

Tags: html, css

[image: Блок новостей]

Доброго времени суток!
Будет выводиться блок новостей вот в таком формате в несколько рядов. Картинки будут различных размеров и пропорций. По ТЗ размер блока с картинкой должен быть 390х290.
Не могу загнать изображение в блок. При изменении `width`, `heigth`, `background-size` картинка изменяется пропорционально и остаются либо пустое место, либо картинка растягивается.

html

```
<div class="nz-thumbnail press-block"
  style="background: url({{- article.image.url -}}) no-repeat ">
    <div class="ninzio-overlay">
        <a class="nz-overlay-before" title="View details" href="{{ url }}">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.......   
.nz-thumbnail {position: relative;}  
........     
.post .press-block {  
    height: 290px;  
}  
........
```

Comment: Пропишите для .press-block стили `background-size: cover` и `background-position: 50% 50%`. Первое css-правило "вписывает" изображение в контейнер, второе - центрирует его по вертикали и горизонтали.

Comment: [Похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729869/css-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA/730114#730114)